# Problem displaying png on IE6

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-6, png

I'm using these codes to fix the png display problem in IE. The strange thing is that sometimes it works and sometimes it doesn't. I included these within `<head>` or my htmls.

```
<!--[if lt IE 7.]>
<script defer type="text/javascript" src="_scripts/pngfix.js"></script>
<![endif]-->
```

Any ideas anyone? And if there's any way to fix this problem with IE6?

Answer (score 3):

Try using [DD_belatedPNG](http://www.dillerdesign.com/experiment/DD_belatedPNG/) instead.

It uses a different technique compared to most of the other IE6 `.png` fixes, and has in my experience been generally more reliable.

Be sure to *precisely* follow the instructions in the ["Usage" section](http://www.dillerdesign.com/experiment/DD_belatedPNG/#usage).

Comment: I tried the following. It's not working for my IE. What have I done wrong?

<!--[if IE 6]>
<script src="_scripts/DD_belatedPNG.js"></script>
<script>
  /* EXAMPLE */
  DD_belatedPNG.fix('_images/img_hmLogo.png');
  
  /* string argument can be any CSS selector */
  /* .png_bg example is unnecessary */
  /* change it to what suits you! */
</script>
<![endif]-->

Comment: You need to pass in a CSS selector, not a path to an image. For example: `DD_belatedPNG.fix('#myLogo');` will fix `<img id="myLogo" />` or `DD_belatedPNG.fix('img');` will fix every `<img />` on the page.

Answer (score 1):

Remove the period:

```
<!--[if lt IE 7]>
```

Comment: Did you test this, or is it just a guess?

Comment: I have had this problem before and this was the solution.