# How to render a PNG with transparency in IE6?

Tags: javascript, html, css, png, internet-explorer-6

I have a very beautiful Web application with attractive icons images. My CSS and all other UI is looking great in all other browsers except IE.

How can I make a PNG to appear properly?

Comment: Google "IE6 PNG fix"? There are numerous methods of going about this.

Comment: try looking at this http://www.twinhelix.com/css/iepngfix/

Comment: what the actually problem in your code? can you put some code here from there you getting problem

Comment: As @James says, this is a very well known issue (there must be dozens of answers to this question just here on SO, let alone across the whole internet). But the real question is why are people still insisting on supporting IE6. **PLEASE** stop supporting this ancient browser -- especially for simple cosmetic things like this, where the site still works. Anyone who really is still using IE6 must surely be used to the internet looking rubbish by now, so there's no reason to bend over backwards for them.

Comment: @Spudley - I guess in india it's still the standard.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6319801/problem-displaying-png-on-ie6/6319900#6319900

Comment: @easwee - gs.statcounter.com reports it at 11% for India, so yes, higher than most other countries. But still low enough to consider dropping support, especially for issues like this which don't affect your actual site functionality. But agreed, it is up to the OP to make that call; I'm just saying it how I see it.

Comment: @Spudley: I feel mostly the same way: http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/81207/these-days-is-it-required-the-testing-for-a-desktop-website-for-ie6-and-ie7-or-i

Comment: @Spudley, those figures often exclude intranet usage. Many enterprises still rely on IE6 -- [2 years ago it was the default at 78% of companies](http://news.cnet.com/8301-17939_109-10231713-2.html) -- so while some developers may have the luxury of ignoring IE6, not all do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Internet Explorer 6 and below, transparetn pngs do not show correctly. The transparent part of the png is not transparent but a solid color. Anyways to fix that problem add this code to your head tag.

```
<script language="JavaScript">
function correctPNG() // correctly handle PNG transparency in Win IE 5.5 & 6.
{
   var arVersion = navigator.appVersion.split("MSIE")
   var version = parseFloat(arVersion[1])
   if ((version >= 5.5) && (document.body.filters)) 
   {
      for(var i=0; i<document.images.length; i++)
      {
         var img = document.images[i]
         var imgName = img.src.toUpperCase()
         if (imgName.substring(imgName.length-3, imgName.length) == "PNG")
         {
            var imgID = (img.id) ? "id='" + img.id + "' " : ""
            var imgClass = (img.className) ? "class='" + img.className + "' " : ""
            var imgTitle = (img.title) ? "title='" + img.title + "' " : "title='" + img.alt + "' "
            var imgStyle = "display:inline-block;" + img.style.cssText 
            if (img.align == "left") imgStyle = "float:left;" + imgStyle
            if (img.align == "right") imgStyle = "float:right;" + imgStyle
            if (img.parentElement.href) imgStyle = "cursor:hand;" + imgStyle
            var strNewHTML = "<span " + imgID + imgClass + imgTitle
            + " style=\"" + "width:" + img.width + "px; height:" + img.height + "px;" + imgStyle + ";"
            + "filter:progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.AlphaImageLoader"
            + "(src=\'" + img.src + "\', sizingMethod='scale');\"></span>" 
            img.outerHTML = strNewHTML
            i = i-1
         }
      }
   }    
}
window.attachEvent("onload", correctPNG);
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Clearly, we have no idea what exactly is not displaying correctly since you've given no information. If you're looking to use Transparent PNG files in IE6, check out this link http://24ways.org/2007/supersleight-transparent-png-in-ie6

Answer (score 1):

You should try this

```
<div style="position:relative; height: 188px; width: 188px;
filter:progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.AlphaImageLoader 
(src='images/image.png',sizingMethod='scale');"></div>
```

or use a JS downloaded from here http://labs.unitinteractive.com/downloads/unitip.zip
or http://www.twinhelix.com/css/iepngfix/